# php push dimensional array

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a DB inert which looks like this:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'mailone@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'mailtwo@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

But I am tryint to build the data with dynamic values eg in a loop add more times:

```
array_push($a,'email' => $this->mail,'votes' => $this->votes);
```

So that I can simply run this later:

```
DB::table('users')->insert($myData);
```

So how can I push a dimensional array?

Comment: What exactly are you looping? Can you show structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly .you can do simply do this , you can push you arrays to the original array so it will create a multidimentinal array.

```
    $a = array();
    array_push($a,array('email' => $this->mail,'votes' =>  $this->votes));
```

Comment: Oh thats how I messed up, I forgot array(

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    $array = [];

    $dataComingFromSomewhere = [];   // Assuming this is your data source

    for($index = 0; $index < count($dataComingFromSomewhere); $index++)
    {
       $newUserArray = ['email' => $dataComingFromSomewhere[$index]->email, 'votes' => $dataComingFromSomewhere[$index]->votes];
       array_push($array, $newUserArray);
    }

    DB::table('users')->insert($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

just this,

```
$myData[]= array('email' => $this->mail,'votes' => $this->votes);
DB::table('users')->insert($myData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Improper use of `array_push()`. To push a single Associative Element it's like:

```
$a['email'] = $this->mail; $a['votes'] = $this->votes;
```

or do this:

```
$a = array_merge($a, array('email' => $this->mail, 'votes' => $this->votes));
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize `$a` as empty array `$a = array()`

Then change the line

```
array_push($a,'email' => $this->mail,'votes' => $this->votes);
```

to

```
array_push($a,array('email' => $this->mail,'votes' => $this->votes));
```

and you can do,

```
DB::table('users')->create($a);
```